# chat application using ruby

Tags: ruby, sockets, chat

I am trying to build a chat application using ruby on linux
,So my client can not send many messages, it simply sends a one message in the first

Server Code :

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'socket'

server = TCPServer.new(2008)

while (session = server.accept) && (input = session.gets)
    puts input

end
```

Client Code :

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'socket'


begin
 clientSession = TCPSocket.new( "localhost", 2008 ) 

rescue StandardError => bang
  puts "Error !! "
else


while !(clientSession.closed?) 

print "Enter message :  "
msg = gets
clientSession.puts msg 
end

end
```

Thanks a lot for your time!!

Comment: What is the error that you're facing?

Comment: I have no error the problem is when I want to send for example 4 messages the client sends just one message :(

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is here:

```
while (session = server.accept) && (input = session.gets)
  puts input
end
```

You are accepting connections in a while loop. What you want instead is to first accept the connection, and then loop through that:

```
connection = server.accept

while (input = connection.gets)
  puts input
end
```

Comment: If you are an active user and since it has helped you. You will have to mark it as accepted. `Ahmed`. Thanks